# Alignment in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a below LWC code where the requirement is to display the label and value next to each other but the value is being shown at the bottom of the label, please suggest

```
<template>
  <lightning-record-view-form
    record-id={productConfigId}
    object-api-name="Apttus_Config2__ProductConfiguration__c"
    density="compact"
  >
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <lightning-layout >
      <lightning-layout-item>
        <div class="slds-p-around_xx-small">
          <label for="proposal">PROPOSAL:</label>
          <lightning-output-field id="proposal" field-name="Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__c" variant="label-hidden">
          </lightning-output-field>
        </div>
      </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
  </lightning-record-view-form>
</template>
```

currently it is showing as below it should be next to each other.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply slds as below. It will bring the label and field in same row:-

```
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <label for="proposal">PROPOSAL:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-output-field id="proposal" field-name="Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__c" variant="label-hidden">
            </lightning-output-field>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Check the playground here:- [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/5kIp-fUMU/14/edit)

Comment: Thank you sanket, could you please confirm if we can use LDS for related parent records?

Comment: Can you create a new thread for your query related to LDS for related parent records?